# How to insert/update data in null value column?

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I have table called `dtr` and it has 5 columns: `id` `student_id` `time_in` `time_out` and `date`.

What I'm doing on my project is to let the user input an ID Number, then the program scans it if the ID Number is in the database. If it's in the database, the first input of ID number will insert data in `time_in` column. And on the second input of the same ID number will insert data in `time_out` column.

This is what I want to happen:

```
if(inputtedIDNumber == fromDatabase)
{
    //ID Number found
    if(the column 'time_out' is null)
    {
        //update the row that 'time_in' has a value and add time in 'time_out' column  
    }
    else
    {
        //add new row and will insert ID Number, time_in, and date
    }
}
else
{
    //ID number not found
}
```

Comment: I see nothing in the code about nulls.

Comment: @Richard I edited it, wish you can understand me.

Comment: So what is the question/problem?

Answer (score 0):

//to update the row that 'time_in' has a value and add time in 'time_out' column you can use :

```
//Update dtr set student_id=@student_id, time_in=@time_in, time_out=@time_out, date=@date where ID = @id;
Update dtr set time_in=@time_in where ID = @id;
```

to insert new row use :

```
Insert into dtr (student_id, time_in,time_out,date) values(@student_id, @time_in, @time_out, @date);
```